# Is it safe to stop a fsck in progress?

Tags: linux, fedora, fsck

I have a server that I rebooted without using the `f` option in my shutdown command, and it started doing a fsck of a very large filesystem... which will take a very long time, as you can imagine. Is it safe to reboot while this is in progress to get around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on the filesystem and the actual checking. E.g. it is usually not a good idea to interrupt a `reiserfsck --rebuild-tree` but nothing can happen when interrupting a read-only fsck of an ext3 filesystem.

Comment: Is there any way to tell exactly what it's doing during boot? `Alt-F` keys don't give me other consoles...

Comment: What exactly do you see? If you see this blue bubble thingy, try hitting ESC.

Comment: I just see a CLI progress bar... it's a text bootup of a CentOS 5.2 installation. In any case, it's finished now -- thank you for your input.

Answer (score 4):

The filesystem check on boot is usually read-only until it finds a problem then it will prompt you before making any changes so it is probably safe to intereupt.

*But* is is quite possible (and not uncommon for servers that need to come back up after a power-out) for it to be set to auto-fix, so unless you know for *sure* that your system is not configured this way let it run to completion for safety.

Most fsck programs are written in such a way that any changes that make are as atomic as possible and they will clean-up (completing or rolling back any current change) before responding to a TERM or INT signal (SIGINT is what is sent to the active process when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is pressed) so even an actively writing fsck should be safe to interrupt, but I woudl not recommend taking the risk - better safe than sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't stop it. Yeah, there probably isn't a problem with an auto fsck triggered byt it being the 37th or what ever mount with out needing one, but probably a good thing to do.

Get a journaled or better file system. Get btrfs (and back up :-D ) .